# Can anyone please tell why I'm getting this error in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

I don't know why it's showing me this error. I tried changing temp1 with other names but it's same.

```
>>  for i = [1:10000]
temp0 = theta0 - ((a/m)*((X(i,1)*theta0 + X(i,2)*theta1) - Y(i))*X(i,1)
temp1 = theta1 - ((a/m)*((X(i,1)*theta0 + X(i,2)*theta1) - Y(i))*X(i,2)
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> temp1 = theta1 - (a/m)*((X(i,1)*theta0 + X(i,2)*theta1) - Y(i))*X(i,2)
        ^
```

Comment: As this was a simple typo, and is unlikely to benefit future visitors to SO, it's probably advisable to remove this question Ashish, especially as it has now been solved for you. Also in future it is courteous to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem (as one below appears to have). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing right parenthese ")" in the expression. Maybe like this

```
temp0 = theta0 - ((a/m)*((X(i,1)*theta0 + X(i,2)*theta1) - Y(i))*X(i,1))
temp1 = theta1 - ((a/m)*((X(i,1)*theta0 + X(i,2)*theta1) - Y(i))*X(i,2))
```

Comment: Can you please tell where? Also, the first and second line is same. Why am I not getting an error in the first one (temp0)?

Comment: @AshishGoel because you use an assignment at an inappropriate place. The interpreter detects this synatx error at the second "=". Add the missing closing parenthese like matusko said

Comment: @AshishGoel if "it worked" please mark this answer as accepted to remove it from the list of unanswered questions. (whether you found it useful and would like to upvote it as well is up to you)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unbalanced set of parentheses. Watch:

```
temp0 = theta0 - 
        (
          (a / m) * 
          (
            (
              X(i,1) * theta0 + X(i,2) * theta1
            ) 
            - Y(i)
          ) 
          * X(i,1)
        % <-- The bracket at this indentation level has not been closed.
```

Octave complains because you haven't closed that parenthesis, and you're therefore attempting to assign to a second variable before having finished the previous statement.